# Scrapy: How to crawl link image before enter the site and crawl the content?

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I'm recently learning Scrapy and using edX.org as a exercising target, but come across with some difficulty.

Say i want to crawl the content in this page:
https://www.edx.org/course/edx/edx-edxdemo101-edx-demo-1038#.U4BRta0zD3E

Everything works fine, except i don't like the image on this page, since it's too big. I find the image provided by the list on page https://www.edx.org/course-list is what i want, and this URL is where my crawler starts with.

How can i combine the image provided by the second URL (course-list) for this course and the corresponding course info as shown in the first URL (specific course info) into an single item? Which mechanism in Scrapy API can help me do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `meta` functionality of Request to pass the `img` url.

```
# parse list page
def parse(self, response):

    sel = Selector(response)

    for e in sel.xpath('...'):
        url = e.xpath('...').extract()[0]
        img = e.xpath('...').extract()[0]
        yield Request(url=url, meta={'img':img}, callback=self.parse_item)

# parse detail page
def parse_item(self, response):

    img = response.meta['img']
    title = '...'

    yield YourItem(title=title, img=img)
```